# How to forbid user to insert 0 on TextBox if it's empty or already 0?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to check that if my `TextBox` (txtmoney) is empty or equal to `0`, it's not allowed to press key <kbd>0</kbd> on keyboard or the number 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it winforms or webforms?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Use `NumericUpdown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before implementing please refer [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) & [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you dont want to allow the 0 to be entered then

```
 private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == '0');
 }
```

To handle textbox text you can try is

```
 private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text) || txtmoney.Text == "0")
    {
        // Do Something 
    }
 }
```

> Note: if you are using winform don't forget to subscribe those event in your code.
>   Example:-

```
txtBox.KeyPress += txtBox_KeyPress;
txtBox.TextChanged += txtBox_TextChanged;
```